Former manager and team keep reaching out with questions despite transferring to a new team
I recently switched to a different team within the same company. This was a transfer that's been in the works for over 6 months and everyone was informed that I was looking for a new opportunity within the company. Once my new role was finalized, my new manager reached out to my old one to discuss a transition plan. After setting up time to hire my backfill, a 1 month handover period was agreed upon.
I proceeded to set up an extensive handover including multiple onboarding sessions for the new hires, working sessions with day-to-day tasks, as well as an extensive document detailing daily responsibilities, upcoming responsibilities, contacts for internal and external teams, and all necessary links. Prior to transitioning I also made sure the team plus my manager were introduced to everyone I worked with both internally and externally and looped into all emails.
It's been about a week since I transferred and I have been getting constant messages from both my previous manager and team-- nearly every single hour. These were simple questions (think: is this client a part of this parent company) that were already covered in my handover and/or was very basic information that you could figure out by googling. Everytime I redirected the team to prioritize speaking to my previous manager (and their current one) they let me know that they had approached him first and he told them to just ask me.
I hate saying no to my team, especially if they're asking for support however these are basic questions which my previous manager knows how to answer. It all came to a boiling point when out of the blue he started dialing me into a call while I was already on another. I messaged him saying I did not have the flexibility to join meetings however I'd be happy to answer questions via chat or email. He said I had to join and that it was urgent concerning a client who was unhappy. For context: the client was unhappy because he had not handled an issue that I'd called out was his responsibility before transitioning. I told him that I had other responsibilities I needed to prioritize at which point he started getting much ruder via chat: he told me that he expected me to join calls when the team needed (not agreed upon prior to my handover) and that he "could" have made me handover for 2 months but had been nice enough to allow me to do so in 1 month. I didn't give in, however I was extremely frustrated at his behavior. My new job is extremely rigorous and I do not have time to prioritize tasks that I've already handed over.
For context, this is a recurring issue with him where he doesn't handle problems until they get out of hand and expects people to clean up his mess. He never pushes back on tasks we shouldn't be handling or that have shortened timelines and for him everything is a priority. I was senior enough to handle his behavior and push back and maintain timelines, however my team is much more junior than I am and I dont know if they will feel empowered to do so. I had expected him to step in once I left, but it appears he doesn't want to.
I am considering chatting with his manager (the head of the department) who I have a good relationship with, however I dont want to burden her unnecessarily and I'm not sure if this will sour my relationship with my previous team members. As much as I'd like to provide support, I dont have the bandwidth to do so and it's not fair to them to have zero management. I'd like some advice as to whether I should handle this myself (and how) or if I should start looping in other folks. At the minimum I might chat to my current manager for advice about all of this.

@keshlam Agreed we can't tell the poster what to do. We can tell them how to work out what to do though.

"At the minimum I might chat to my current manager for advice about all of this." Why haven't you already? From what you tell us, you should've started doing this days ago.

What is your question that we can help you with ?


At the minimum I might chat to my current manager for advice about all of this.

100% this. You've done all the right things here, it's time to bring this up to your manager because it's affecting the work you can do for your new team. They can give you guidance on how to approach this - which honestly is hopefully "they'll talk to your old team's manager".

+1 Even though supposedly your manager said it was OK to help them, that doesn't mean that your manager has any idea just how much of your time they are taking up.

This is what managers are for.  Tell them how many hours you are spending. Round up. They are responsible to set your priorities in line with what the company needs. They may tell you to ignore these requests, and you should do that.  They may tell your prior organization to provide some budget for your time if they want you to continue.  You might suggest to your manager that this will hamper your development into a fully useful part of their organization, but if that is what the company needs you will do that.  You can also suggest that your manager demand a transition plan to get you out.

"Boss, please prioritize my time!"

Your manager should have been involved from the start and 'managing' your work. You should NOT be communicating with about tasks and/or doing another teams work without your managers formal approval.
Talk to your manager asap and make sure they know that if you help the other team it will impact on your work for your current team, and then it's their problem to solve.
Your manager is supposed to be like a buffer between you and the outside in situations that impact on work, it's one of their primary responsibilities.

You take this straight to your manager. Your manager would normally expect that 100% of your working time is spent on jobs you do for him or her. If you decide to do unpaid overtime, no difference, 100% of your unpaid overtime should be spent on jobs you do for your manager (but don't do that).
It's up to your manager to tell you whether you are allowed to do work for the old team and how much, and up to them to tell the manager of your old team how much they can expect from you. It's not your decision to make.

I disagree, it is OP's decision, as OP knows the situation best. Approach OP's manager "hey boss, the old team pulls me in for 5 hours a week. I think they should do more themselves and only ask me just specific questions. Do you agree I write this to my old manager?"

That’s what a manager for. Do you want to be in front of HR explaining why you refuse to follow the old managers instructions? And then your new manager “forgets” that you asked him?

Several other answers have (correctly) advised you to talk to your own manager. I wanted to address this specific line in your question:

I am considering chatting with his manager (the head of the department) who I have a good relationship with, however I dont want to burden her unnecessarily and I'm not sure if this will sour my relationship with my previous team members.

As a rule of thumb, it is rarely a good idea to go directly to upper or middle management with issues like this. What you describe is a straightforward difference of opinion between you and someone else (who used to be your manager, but frankly that is irrelevant), over your current job responsibilities. At most corporations, your (new) manager is fully empowered to resolve that difference of opinion by telling you what to work on and/or telling the other person when and how they should be talking to you. If you escalate directly to someone higher up the food chain, your new manager may see this as "going over their head," which at the very least could create bad feelings, and at some workplaces, might be seen as outright insubordination. There is also a fairly good chance that, as soon as the higher-up finishes talking to you, they immediately go to your manager and ask "why didn't you handle this before it landed on my desk?" Most managers do not like it when their reports put them in that position without fair warning.
There are situations where you need to talk to higher level managers, but these are usually more complicated scenarios where the "correct" outcome is less straightforward. A good line manager will tell you when you need to talk to higher managers, will assist you in preparing for such conversations, and will advocate on your behalf when you are not in the room.


At the minimum I might chat to my current manager for advice about all of this.

As others have said, this is the most important. Here is what you propose to your new manager:

It's been about a week since I transferred and I have been getting constant messages from both my previous manager and team-- nearly every single hour.

The reason they do this is is because it keeps working. You have to stop responding. Do not respond to direct messages, do not join calls, do not explain your decision. Do not communicate.
Optional: At the end of the week, communicate once to everyone who messaged you that you are no longer available for project related questions and to please direct their questions to your old manager.

Despite your carefully planned handover, it's still only been a week since you left the team so your ex-workers and your ex-manager are probably only just realising what it actually means to not have you immediately available to help anymore and are still in the "denial" stage of adjusting :-).
Now that I've read it back to myself, the following points sound like passive-aggressive Machiavellian dickweedery, but it's worked for me recently with a new colleague who was a pure-blood Help Vampire who now spends a bit more time trying to solve their own problems before bothering other people (thankfully without me having to involve our respective line managers):

whenever they ask for help, don't reply immediately - be ever so slightly unavailable and wait a few (or more) minutes to reply. Ask them to send you the details by email / chat and you can take a look when you have time "this afternoon" or "in a couple of hours" (or whatever) as you're "in the middle of something right now". By the time you reply they might have already found the answer since you've forced them to look by themselves.

ask them to create a ticket for the request in your work tracking system so that "your line manager can see how busy you are". If they try to share additional details via email or chat ask them to add it to the ticket instead.

instead of giving them the answer, point them to the appropriate location in your handover notes. If the answer isn't in your handover notes, add it and then tell them you've updated the notes. If the answer is in some general online documentation send a link to the page rather than give the answer.


These all add a slight penalty to them coming to you for help and nudges them toward solving their own problems. Obviously if it goes on for too long then mention it to your line manager as an fyi:

Hey, Line Manager, just to let you know my old team is taking up a bit of my time, but I'm slowly weaning them off me. I should be fully available to work on our project soon.

and if it still goes on then escalate it:

Hey, Line Manager, I'm still spending a lot of time supporting my old team - should I keep doing that or can you suggest what to do?

You could also do an Internet search for terms like how to handle a "help vampire" (the quoted string will help avoid generic vampire fandom) and pick out any suggestions that are as gentle / brutal as you're comfortable with.

For me, an online search for "Help Vampire Survival Guides" turns up nothing but stuff for a certain video game. Perhaps you could links to some pages you mean?

@DanielR.Collins - In the spirit of my answer I was going to post a LMGTFY link, but their certificate expired :-). Try something like how to handle a "help vampire" for some more relevant results (the quoted string will help avoid generic vampire fandom). I'll update my answer with a better search query...

OK, so there was an agreed upon transition period of one month.  But apparently that agreement was not specific enough.  So, with potential of each working day throughout a calendar month, how many of your work hours was that supposed to consume?  One hour?  Four hours?  Eight hours?
You should consult with your current manager and establish a distinct time boundary.  This way, you (or your manager) can communicate this boundary to your old team.  Once that's done, keep a mental running note when you get these intrusive emails and calls.  When the boundary is crossed, STOP, and go back to your current work.
Don't apologize when the boundary is reached.  If there's pushback, refer them to your current manager.  This takes the pressure off you.  The other thing it does, hopefully, is forces your old manager to prioritize what things actually need to be escalated to you versus things that do not.  Right now, the old manager is dumping stuff on you because there is no boundary.  It would have to change if the boundary was established.
